# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webbrowser' - Anaconda - Jupyter Notebook - MacOS

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I am trying to launch Jupyter Notebook from the Anaconda Navigator in a MacOS but I am getting this error from the terminal:

```
Last login: Tue Oct 19 21:30:32 on ttys000
ana@Anas-MacBook-Pro ~ % /Applications/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 33, in <module>
    import webbrowser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webbrowser'
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Is there a way I could fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

install **webbrowser** module by typing

```
pip install webbrowser
```

or

```
pip3 install webbrowser
```

in your terminal